# child links in quick launch navigation in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247080.aspx

based on example on this site for getting quick lunch url and quick lunch title

we have something like this

```
while (nodeEnumerator.moveNext()) {

            var node = nodeEnumerator.get_current();
            nodeInfo += '{"title":"' + node.get_title() + '",' + '"link":"' + node.get_url() + '"},'; 

               }
```

but if any of those navigation urls have any childs I don't know how to get that

so how to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SP.NavigationNode.children property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj247143.aspx) to get the collection of child nodes of the navigation node.

> Note: `SP.NavigationNode.children property` needs to be requested
>   *explicitly* in query, this is why in the below example it is specified via `Include` expression:
>   `ctx.load(quickLaunchNodes,'Include(Title,Url,Children)');`

**Example**

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var quickLaunchNodes = web.get_navigation().get_quickLaunch();        
ctx.load(quickLaunchNodes,'Include(Title,Url,Children)');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        printNodesInfo(quickLaunchNodes);
    },
    function(sender, args) {
        console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    });

function printNodesInfo(nodes){
    nodes.get_data().forEach(function(node){
        var childNodes = node.get_children();
        console.log(String.format('{0} child nodes:',node.get_title()));
        childNodes.get_data().forEach(function(childNode){
            console.log(String.format('Title: {0} Url: {1}',childNode.get_title(),childNode.get_url())); 
        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: awesome I have one more problem, I am building a hybrid mobile app for connecting to sharepoint and I tried many thing but I couldn't pass the authentication do you have solution for that?

Comment: The [following article](https://blogs.office.com/2014/05/12/net-and-javascript-libraries-for-office-365-apis/) could be used as a starting point